# Is it possible, and how to refactor this with lambda linq

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, refactoring

I'm trying to determine a way where if a name is in the WorkedDataPoint list, and falls on any of the days in totalDaysInDateRange it counts it.  The basic premice, is if these two dates match, the person worked that day - I'm trying to get a count of "worked" days.  There also may be more than one entry per day per user, and we can only count the one, one for the day so DistinctBy in "morelinq"seemed a good choice...

What I have here should work fine, compiler at work so can't say for sure.  But how would I do this with linq lambda expressions to make it more concise - particularly the foreach loop, can that in lambda in this application somehow?

```
    public class WorkedDatapoint
    {
        public string AssignerName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }
        public bool AssignedToOther { get; set; }
    }
    List<DateTime> totalDaysInDateRange
    List<WorkedDataPoint> AssignersList
    testtech = "Bobby"

    //The two lists are loaded here

    int totalDaysWorked = 0;
    foreach (var day in totalDaysInDateRange)
    {
        if (AssignersList.Where(d => testtech.Contains(d.AssignerName)).DistinctBy(d => d.Date.Date).Any(d => d.Date.Date == day.Date)
        {
            totalDaysWorked++;      
        }
    }
```

Edit: I think I got it but can't test til tomorrow.  Any way to declare that variable TotalDaysWorked inline or is that asking too much?

```
          int totalDaysWorked = 0;
          totalDaysInDateRange.ForEach((day) =>
          {
              if (AssignersList
                .Where(d => testtech.Contains(d.AssignerName))
                .DistinctBy(d => d.Date.Date)
                .Any(d => d.Date.Date == day.Date))
          { totalDaysWorked++; }});
```

This method is "crunching" thousands of records, so thoughts on optimization for speed (plenty of RAM and Intel-I7) would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: Making things more "fluent" is not always a good thing - it doesn't always improve readability, and typically makes debugging harder, as you cannot stop at different steps as easily. As for performance, you may be able to do a parallel foreach

Answer (score 1):

Can do something like this:

```
int totalDaysWorked = totalDaysInDateRange.Intersect(AssignersList.Select(b => b.Date)).Count();
```

As Except uses Set internally:

```
int count = totalDaysInDateRange.Count() - totalDaysInDateRange.Except(AssignersList.Select(b => b.Date)).Count();
```

**Warning:**
For large numbers, linq is incredibly slow and should be banned. More about this [here](http://www.schnieds.com/2009/03/linq-vs-foreach-vs-for-loop-performance.html):

Answer (score 0):

You can write linq query for your problem like:-

```
var AssignerDaysCount = assignerList.Where(filter => 
totalDaysInDateRange.Contains(filter.Date.Date))
.GroupBy(item => item.AssignerName)
.Select(lst => new { AssignerName = lst.Key, DaysCount = lst.Select(cnt   =>   cnt.Date).Distinct().Count() })
.ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to join totalDaysInDateRange and AssignersList on Date. Then Group by AssignerName and Date. you will get the dates

```
var jointList = totalDaysInDateRange.Join(
                        AssignersList,
                        p => p,
                        c => c.Date,
                        (p, c) => new { c.AssignerName, c.Date }
                    ).Distinct().GroupBy(x => x.AssignerName).Select(group => 
                        new { 
                             AssignerName = group.Key, 
                             Count = group.Count() 
                        }).ToList();
```